# SetActiveSheet() works in editor but won't work on a time-driven trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble making a function to change the active sheet between 2 sheets from the same worksheet a few times a day.

My code works fine in the script editor when I run it manually, but when set as a time-driven trigger it will not run at all. I am running it from the account that owns the worksheet and setting up the trigger via "current project's triggers." 
I cannot find any specific reason why it would not run on a time-driven trigger

The code I'd like to run is as follows-

```js
// This function cycles the dashboards
function getCycled() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
    // ifs to make this cycle only if already displaying a DB
    // If DB 2.0
    if (sheetName == "Dashboard 2.0") {
        // change to Q/S
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Quality/Safety"));
    }
    // If Q/S
    if (sheetName == "Quality/Safety") {
        // change to DB 2.0
        ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Dashboard 2.0"));
    }
}
```

I've even tried to simplify the code further to make a basic change. Again, it runs in the editor just fine, but still won't run on a time-driven trigger. Is this an issue with my code or am I not understanding something about installable/time-driven triggers?

```js
function getCycledB() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: so what would you expect it to happen if there are many people working on the sheet at trigger time, or none at all? (so you see why that function has a meaning only when a specific user runs it from a specific browser instance)

Answer (score 1):

I believe time triggers won't work well with `getActiveSpreadsheet`, because at there is no "active" sheet. It should work if you get the spreadsheet with `openById` and pass the unique id of your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

The code below gets a spreadsheet using its ID and puts it in the variable ss.

The spreadsheet is NOT physically opened on the client side.
It is opened on the server only (so the script can access it.).

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GOOGLEID");
```

You will receive the unique ID for the spreadsheet. 
You can find the ID if you look up your sheet ID by running this code and saving the results in the log.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 Logger.log(sheet.getSheetId());
```

The ID should look something like the information in bold.
https://docs.google.com/a/yourdomain.com/spreadsheets/d/**1p8FzOBwGELiKyjnhwoWqfG2l8mt1o889Ln5RKtUsng**/edit?usp=sharing